# Open URL captured from XML file using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri and Cucumber (selenium-webdriver) and I have this XML file:

```
<root>
  <records>
    <record>
      <rowA>www.google.com</rowA>
    </record>
  </records>
</root>
```

Then, I create these steps:

```
When /^I open my xml file$/ do
  file = File.open("example.xml")
  @xml = Nokogiri::XML(file)
  file.close
end

Then /^I should see the url google$/ do
  url = @xml.xpath('///rowA')  
  print(url[0].content)
  @browser.get url[0].content
end
```

With this line `@browser.get url[0].content` I'm trying to open the browser with the URL captured from the XML file but I received an error:

```
f.QueryInterface is not a function (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your xml is incorrect (missing </records> )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write the code this way:

```
When /^I open my xml file$/ do
  @xml = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("example.xml"))
end

Then /^I should see the url google$/ do
  @browser.get 'http://' + @xml.at('rowA').content
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to the URL that you are trying to navigate to (rather than how the URL is retrieved).

The exception can be reproduced by hard-coding the URL to retrieve:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get('www.google.com')
#=> f.QueryInterface is not a function (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

You need to add the "http://" to the URL:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
#=> No exception
```

In other words, the XML document should be changed to:

```
<root>
  <records>
    <record>
      <rowA>http://www.google.com</rowA>
    </record>
</root>
```